# Move files with certain extensions only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently using the `Directory.Move` method to copy files from one location to another. What i would like to do is only move files with certain extensions (.dbf, .ini & .txt). If the original folder doesn't contain any of these files then i just want to create an empty directory

Current code I'm using is...

```
Dim n As Integer

If lb1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

For n = 0 To UBound(AllDetails)

    If AllDetails(n).uName & " - " & AllDetails(n).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(n).uOps = lb1.SelectedItem Then

        If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(aMailbox & "\" & AllDetails(n).uFile) Then
            Directory.Move(zMailbox & AllDetails(n).uFile, aMailbox & "\" & AllDetails(n).uFile)
            lb3.Items.Add(AllDetails(n).uName & " - " & AllDetails(n).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(n).uOps)
        Else

            lb3.Items.Add(AllDetails(n).uName & " - " & AllDetails(n).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(n).uOps)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
```

All the variables are declared and this works but moves the entire folder contents

Comment: If you want to copy files, then why are you using `Directory.Move`?

Comment: What type is contained in the array AllDetails and what is the meaning of its properties

Comment: **I'm** using `Directory.Move` as the files are contained within a folder that is uniquely named and the whole folder is being copied. Is there a better way? Basically these are job files and the "All Details" array is information from a few lines within a text files that identify the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use each extension as a search pattern for `File.GetFiles`, then use `Directory.Move` on each file returned.  Something like this might help:

```
    For Each OldFile As String In (From s In {".dbf", ".ini", ".txt"}
                                From f In Directory.GetFiles(zMailbox & AllDetails(n).uFile, s)
                                Select f)
        Directory.Move(OldFile, aMailbox & "\" & AllDetails(n).uFile & "\" & Path.GetFileName(OldFile))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is certain file extensions only? well `Open File Dialog` can filter that for you

Let's say you call this operation with a button click:

```
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()


    fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "the initial directory you want to look at first"

    'this filters the available files to be opened!
    fd.Filter = "dbf files|*.dbf*|ini files|*.ini*|Text files|*.txt*"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2 'set's the default files to open first as .ini
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True

    If fd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'Copy the file to the location using the copyer subroutin
        resulta.Text = fd.FileName.ToString
        Copyer(fd.FileName.Tostring, "the location where you want to copy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Now for the copying of the file, have a look at this subroutine. This subroutine checks first if the file exists. If it does, it deletes it, then copies the new file.

```
Public Sub Copyer(ByVal theFile As String, ByVal Lokasyon As String)
    Try

        Dim resultpath As String = Lokasyon
        If System.IO.File.Exists(resultpath) = True Then

            System.IO.File.Delete(resultpath) 
            'this deletes the file so you can overwrite it.
        End If
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(theFile, resultpath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please let me know if this has helped you.

Comment: Actually, no, it's not.

Comment: But I usually do it anyway. I just got interrupted. This is not a solution to the problem. The OP wants to move all files with those extensions, not just one file.